# SSRS how to get amount value from specific field

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that groups the rows by store.

The report is laid out like this:

Store1 |  $Sales_Amount | Total_Sales_Amount
Store2 |  $Sales_Amount | Total_Sales_Amount
Store3 |  $Sales_Amount | Total_Sales_Amount

My problem is that I need to subtract a certain amount that belongs to a field of category when that field is equal to a "Gift coupon".  There are hundreds of of items in the category field so I don't include the category field in the report body.

What I did is that I created a calculated field like: iif(Fields!category = "GiftCoupon", Fields!Amount.Value, 0) and added it to the report body.  However, this is not working.

I am wondering if somebody can advise me on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula:

```
=IIF(Fields!category = "GiftCoupon", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)
```

won't work because, as you say, you

> ...don't include the category field in the report body.

If your dataset is retrieved using SQL, then you can do this in your query:

```
SELECT StoreId, Amount, CASE WHEN Category = 'GiftCoupon' THEN Amount END AS GiftCoupons
FROM Sales
```

You could also do this using another dataset, let's call it `GiftCoupons`, which totals the gift coupons by store:

```
SELECT StoreId, SUM(Amount) As Amount
FROM Sales
WHERE Category = 'GiftCoupon'
GROUP BY StoreId
ORDER BY StoreId
```

and then looking up the total gift coupons for that store by doing a `LOOKUP` of the `GiftCoupons` dataset in your expression in your report:

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!StoreId.Value, Fields!StoreId.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, "GiftCoupons")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If this solved your problem you should accept it as the answer (green tick) and upvote it so that the next person to search on this issue knows that the answer solves it.